# Call multiple classes without switch-case or if-else

Tags: switch-statement

I want to know weather is is possible or not, a way to call different classes on the basis of an integer value without conditional statements like switch case?

What I am having is:

```
int val = // getting some value here from a method
String data = // getting some value here from a method

switch(val)
{
    case 1:
    {
      new TempClass1(data);
      break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
      new TempClass2(data);
      break;
    }
}
```

What I want is like:

```
int val = // getting some value here from a method
String data = // getting some value here from a method
new TempClass(val, data);
```

This should call the object of TempClass1 or TempClass1 as per "val"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should call the object of TempClass1 or TempClass1 as per "val" ? Both classes are same.

Use `if ... else if` conditions

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a Factory for the classes, assuming your two classes share a base class named TempBaseClass:

```
class TempClassFactory {

    static public TempBaseClass getTempClass(int val, String data)
    {
        switch(val)
        {
            case 1:
            {
              return new TempClass1(data);
              break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
              return new TempClass2(data);
              break;
            }

            default:
                throw new Exception("Bad value");
        }
    }

}

int val = // getting some value here from a method
String data = // getting some value here from a method
TempClassFactory::getTempClass(val, data);
```

Comment: I do not want to use conditional constructs because number of "TempClass"s will be huge around 150 and every "TempClass" has its own specific work. So calling their individual constructors in cases has no point. Im looking for some other way around, if it is possible.

Comment: You will have to make the distinction between the classes somewhere. The best you can do is using a common abstract base class into which you place all the common code.